# Does the volume of water involved affect rate of electrolysis?

Tags: electrolysis, hydrogen

I am working on the design for a homemade PEM electrolyzer, and my goal is to make it as compact as possible, so as to allow easy transport. My question, as it relates to that, is whether - with the same applied current - the volume of water inside the electrolyzer would influence the rate of decomposition into H2 and O2.

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors that would influence the rate, e.g. area, spacing and type of electrodes, electrolyte, current and current *density*, etc. However, if the *only* factor changed was volume (i.e. electrodes are fully immersed and always at the *top* of the solution on a float, not at the *bottom* where pressure might change), volume would have no effect *at first*.

However, as the reaction proceeds and the concentration of the electrolyte starts to change, due to water loss and possibly due to dissolution of electrodes, the concentration would change *more slowly* with a large volume of electrolyte. Therefore, there might be a second-order difference as electrolysis proceeds.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however I'm a little unclear what you mean by there being a "second-order" difference. And my electrodes will be made from graphene oxide, which is not easy to corrode as it transfers current with a high degree of efficiency without breaking down.